# Can belief propagation be used to infer latent variables?

Tags: bayesian, inference, graphical-model, belief-propagation

Consider a simple Bayes net of linear Gaussian, $A\rightarrow B \leftarrow C$. If $B$ is observed, $A$ and $C$ are hidden (assume we have set priors for the hiddent variables), can we use belief propagation to infer the values of $A$ and $C$?